IC identification for led driver board

SOURCE
I want to identify 3 integrated circuits on the Sony LED driver card and find their datasheets.
4 integrated AN37011B, these are most likely LED driver integrated circuits. But I couldn't find the datasheet.
sn358 (maybe KODENSHI_AUK CORP.)(maybe lm358  dual opamp ?)
3213

https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/AN37011B has a link which claims to have the AN37011B datasheet, but you need to register to view the datasheet which I haven't attempted. Only information found so far is the Panasonic Semiconductor Selection Guide which describes the AN37011B as a LED driver for backlights 4 ch internal support (185 V/200 mA DC max. per channel), PWM intensity adjustment, linear intensity  adjustment compatible, built-in protection functions.

"SN" is a prefix commonly used by Texas Instruments.
